# Possible to use an Amazon S3 bucket for the /public directory in a Heroku Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm trying to figure out how to share a bunch *(read: thousands)* of static HTML files between potentially a few Heroku dynos.

Obviously the dynos will have separate filesystems (not to mention that they are epheremal) so there doesn't seem to be a workable solution there.

Generating these pages will be fairly expensive (and could change) so I don't want to have to frequently generate on each dyno.

Is there a way to set up Rails/Heroku to look in an S3 bucket for the /public directory?  I don't want to put the info into the database as I'd like to keep this completely static and servable via a CDN.

Comment: Do you need to access the files from the app code itself or could you just serve requests for those files straight from s3

Comment: All I would need to be able to do is push new files to the S3 bucket from the Rails app. Ideally, a request for say `/blog/my-post.html` should check the S3 bucket for the file, then if doesn't exist would fall through to the Rails app.  Any of the Heroku dynos would need to be able to push modifications to the file structure on S3.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of writing data to s3, any of the aws gems out there will do the trick. If I were you I'd be looking at the official aws sdk or fog.

With fog you can write a file (assuming `storage` is a Fog::Storage object ) with something like

```
storage.directories.new(:key => 'bucket_name').files.create(:key => 'filename', :body => data)
```

data can be a string or an io object such as a file.

You could have a route that sent requests to a controller that did

```
storage.directories.new(:key => 'bucket_name').files.head(file_name)
```

To see if the file exists or not. Depending on your needs you might want to cache the fact that the file exists so that you don't have to call out to s3 every time.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how I'd set up the Rails app to check for the S3 file then fall back to Thin/unicorn? I'm pretty clear on how to write to S3, I'm just not 100% sure on how to set up the app so that I get some benefit out of the external storage.

Comment: I don't have anything cleverer in mind than to use the head method as I described to check for the presence of the file. If you cache those checks it should be pretty quick